# Best way to make www.example.com AND example.com use the same session variables?

Tags: php, linux, apache, ubuntu, apache2

I'm working on a webpage (let's call it example.com) and added the DNS record under CNAME (Alias):

```
Host Record Points    to  TTL
www  example.com       14400
```

However when I navigate through example.com, the session variables that are set are not retained if I go to www.example.com

What is the best way to make www.example.com AND example.com use the same session variables?

I'm using ubuntu 12.04, php5, apache2.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName www.example.com
    Redirect 301 / http://example.com/
    DocumentRoot /var/www/public_html
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/public_html>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined

Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
</Directory>
```

Comment: Surely the simple option would be to redirect from www.mysite.com to just mysite.com.

Comment: Why do you have both variations in the first place? Would it not make much more sense to redirect one to the other?

Comment: As lonesomeday wrote you should use 301 redirect (.htaccess) because all search engines will treat this website as 2 different websites and in search results you can have 2 different links to the same page which is not right. Its very important to positioning in google and others.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> What is the best way to make www.mysite.com AND mysite.com use the same session variables?

The best way is to not have both host names running the same site.

Pick one of them to be canonical, then redirect everything from the other to the canonical one.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.com
Redirect 301 / http://www.example.com
etc
```

Comment: Hmm - I'm getting a syntax error.  How do I make www.mysite.com redirect to the canonical mysite.com?

Comment: `Redirect 301 / http://example.com/` in the VHost for www.example.com (this approach does require a separate vhost for each).

Comment: Hmm, I tried that, but my webpage isn't loading anymore.  See my edit, it contains the file in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled

Comment: I found a different way to get it to work.  I only include the `ServerName www.mysite.com` in a single virtual host, and since the DNS record is set, `www.mysite.com` will automatically redirect to `mysite.com`.  Essentially this is the same at my config file in my original post, minus the `Redirect 301 / http://mysite.com/` line

Answer (score 2):

The best way You should go is to redirect `mysite.com` to `www.mysite.com` or vice versa - to have just one site (one content) for the domain alias...