# Cookies Are Only Set For Site With www. Prefix

Tags: php, apache, cookies

So I'm creating a site where users must login. If the user wishes that the site remember his login, I set a cookie to remember this data. However, the cookie seems to be set for the site www.mysite.com. This seems to mean that if I visit my site with the address mysite.com (without the www.), the cookie can no longer be accessed. How do I make so that a cookie set on either site can be accessed by both sites?

Comment: Perhaps duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/348282/php-cookie-domain-subdomain-control

Comment: Hm, tricky, you know what, counter to all good practices, let's consult [that dreadful manual](http://nl3.php.net/setcookie), and let's hope we notice the `$domain` parameter....

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to make www.mysite.com AND mysite.com use the same session variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11080989/best-way-to-make-www-mysite-com-and-mysite-com-use-the-same-session-variables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to use both.  Choose one, it's better for SEO as well.  I would personally just redirect through the htaccess to the www and keep it standard.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: My .htaccess file already has this directive in it:    `RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L,QSA]` Should I just put your code right below it?

Comment: Above it, those are just limiting the file and directories and a full url rewrite.

Answer (score 3):

Brian Scott already properly answered the question, but I thought I would add this:

In my opinion if you are allowing a user to "remember" their login, then you'll want to maintain specific control over how/where/why/when and that includes maintaining a secure connection.

For my projects that involved any kind of login I always make sure I have the appropriate SSL certificate and secure connection, then I check the URL they are using to access the site and redirect to make sure they stay within my secure domain.  For example I check for a www. and https prefixes and always redirect to https://www.domain.com ...  just my two cents.

**EDIT:** In response to comment.  Just real rough, but something like this:

```
if (($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] != '443') || ($_SERVER['HTTPS'] != 'on') || (!strstr ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 'www'))) {
  header ("Location: https://www.mydomain.com");
  exit();
}
```

**2nd EDIT:** Two errors in my roughly typed code.

Comment: good point to make. Also, SEO will generally be higher if there's a server redirect response to the common url for the site rather than multiple paths to the same content.

Comment: How do I set up such a redirect?

Comment: Edited post with some sample code which you would put at the very top of your handling page (or all pages within the secure area).

Comment: Thank you for the code, I am beginning to understand everything.

Comment: No prob.  I noticed two errors with my code and fixed them for your (just in case you had used it).

Answer (score 2):

Set your cookie for **.mysite.com** instead of **www.mysite.com**. That way the cookie will recognize the common domain suffix and be compatible with both urls.

Comment: I did what you suggested but now the opposite issue is occurring. The site reads the cookies properly on mysite.com but on www.mysite.com, the site operated as if no cookies exist.

Comment: @user532493: I'm not sure why, I've used this method many times in the past succesfully. It might be worth posting your code that creates the cookie to ensure it's being performed correctly.